# Error installing RVM: requiring BASH 3.2.25 (you have 4.3.42(4)-release)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rvm

I'm attempting to install RVM, and I have a more recent version of BASH. I assume that it needs a version that is 3.2.25 or more recent. I've seen a few post online about it, but they've all been dated or no longer relevant to the current code. Here is what I put in cmd (I have Windows 10 pro).

```
 curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=enabled --ruby --rails
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    143      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   155
100 22865  100 22865    0     0   9566      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 45730
Input file specified two times.

BASH 3.2.25 required (you have 4.3.42(4)-release)
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: What can I do to resolve this error? It doesn't continue with the installation.

Comment: This issue might already be solved here: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/2346

Comment: @user2699706 I have the updated version of the code where they made the changes in that thread. So, I already have the results of that solution, but I'm still getting the error. As for the bash profile part of the solution, I'm not sure I understand what happened there. But I certainly have the code changes that were made.

Comment: There's not much to the check; it grabs the value of `$BASH_VERSION` and does some mucking about with `sort`. I'd try running those commands outside of [the script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer) to see if you get the expected result.

Comment: @miken32 Is it possible there is something wrong with bash sort? When I run the commands outside the script, the only thing I can get is the error "Input file specified two times."

Comment: I didn't even notice that error in your original post, actually! I know what the problem is, give me a minute to write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Input file specified two times," displayed when the check was run, is output from the Windows sort command. If you run this command it will show you which instance of the `sort` command is being run:

```
which sort
```

To ensure the correct version is always used, alter your `PATH` to include the typical Bash executable paths (`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`) before any Windows ones. Or, simply remove the Windows paths from your `PATH`.

Where you change this depends on how you've installed Bash (Cygwin, git-bash, etc.) but is typically a file in your home directory called `.profile` or `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is ~/.bash_profile,
Because your head is wrong.
If you are using:

```
export PATH=some/other/path:${PATH}
```

Let's change to:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:some/other/path
```

Hope this help!